# Multivariate linear regression in Python

Tags: python, regression, library, software-recommendation

I'm looking for a Python package that implements multivariate linear regression.

(Terminological note: *multivariate* regression deals with the case where there are more than one dependent variables while *multiple* regression deals with the case where there is one dependent variable but more than one independent variables.)

Comment: I'm also interested in this but want just the feature vector after the non-linear transform. So on row would be $[1,x_1,x_2,x_1x_2,x_1^2,x_2^2]$ say for degree 2 model with 2 variables.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can still use [sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression).  Simply make the output `y` a matrix with as many columns as you have dependent variables.  If you want something [non-linear](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#polynomial-regression-extending-linear-models-with-basis-functions), you can try different basis functions, use polynomial features, or use a different method for regression (like a NN).

Comment: Are you asking specifically about multivariate logistic regression?  As in you want to perform many classifications at once?  Multivariate _linear_ regression is certainly implemented.  Logistic regression would have to be framed differently to use the sklearn library.

Comment: Whoops, sorry I misread, I was reading the sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression documentation thinking about linear regression. I'll remove my comment to avoid confusing future readers. Thanks!

Comment: wish you would have emphasized how to get the polynomial feature vector...

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun you can compute the feature by hand by forming tuples $seq =(d_1,...,d_N)$ such that $Sum(seq) = \sum^N_{i=1} \leq D$. Once you form those tuples each entry indicates the power the current raw feature should be raised by. So say $(1,2,3)$ would map to the monomial $x_1 x_2^2 x_3^3$.

The code to get the tuples is:

```
def generate_all_tuples_for_monomials(N,D):
    if D == 0:
        seq0 = N*[0]
        sequences_degree_0 = [seq0]
        S_0 = {0:sequences_degree_0}
        return S_0
    else:
        # S_all = [ k->S_D ] ~ [ k->[seq0,...,seqK]]
        S_all = generate_all_tuples_for_monomials(N,D-1)# S^* = (S^*_D-1) U S_D
        print(S_all)
        #
        S_D_current = []
        # for every prev set of degree tuples
        #for d in range(len(S_all.items())): # d \in [0,...,D_current]
        d = D-1
        d_new = D - d # get new valid degree number
        # for each sequences, create the new valid degree tuple
        S_all_seq_for_deg_d = S_all[d]
        for seq in S_all[d]:
            for pos in range(N):
                seq_new = seq[:]
                seq_new[pos] = seq_new[pos] + d_new # seq elements dd to D
                if seq_new not in S_D_current:
                    S_D_current.append(seq_new)
        S_all[D] = S_D_current
        return S_all
```

then it should be easy to do regression if you know linear algebra.

```
c = pseudo_inverse(X_poly)*y
```

example. Probably better to do regularized linear regression though if your interested in generalization.

---

Acknowledgements to [Yuval is CS exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/80549/how-does-one-generate-all-the-terms-of-a-multivariate-polynomial-algorithmically/80550#comment171459_80550) for the help.